# react-native + android error : How to fix? - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7

Tags: mobile-automation, android-automation, azure-devops

I am trying to build android application. Use this .apk to consume for Azure CI-CD for distribution & mobile automation. While executing command **./gradlew clean** or **./gradlew assembleRelease** facing below error :

> **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7**

Please let me know if anyone face/fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify which gradle version installed on your machine and make changes in my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-bin.zip
```

*Note - for me gradle 6.2 works perfectly considering my project. May vary in your case.*

Then I found - Java version is not supporting to all versions. **Java 16 will not support**

**Solution:**

- Try to install **Java 8** or **Java 11** version